Is there a new method for ctx.bumps.get in 0.30.0
I've encountered a problem trying to reuse an old project.
I'm trying to build the project but the cli throws this error at me: "this is an associated function, not a method" for using *ctx.bumps.get("treasury_account").unwrap();
I hope someone can help me. Thank you!
    pub fn init_treasury(ctx: Context<InitAccounts>) -> Result<()> {
    msg!("treasury account");
    ctx.accounts.treasury_account.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("treasury_account").unwrap();

    Ok(())
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitAccounts<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(init, payer = payer, space = 8+1, seeds=[b"treasury"], bump)]
    pub treasury_account: Account<'info, TreasuryAccount>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct TreasuryAccount {
    pub bump: u8,
}


To get the canonical bump of the treasury_account
    let treasury_account = &mut ctx.accounts.treasury_account;
    treasury_account.bump = ctx.bumps.treasury_account;

